# Deleting a global attribute through phpMyAdmin in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I ran this bit of code to add an attribute to all of my categories

```
<?php 
require_once('app/Mage.php');  Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;
$attribute  = array(
'type' => 'string',
'label'=> 'Category Tagline',
'input' => 'text',
'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
'visible' => true,
'required' => false,
'user_defined' => true,
'default' => "",
'group' => "General Information"
 );
 $installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'category_tagline_main', $attribute);
 $installer->endSetup();
 ?>
```

Afterwards my entire site is crashing now, and all I get is an error screen. Is there anyway to undo the SQL query or delete the attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is perfectly valid and it shouldn't break your website. You should however be more cautious next time - make full backup, at least of the database.

To deleted the attribute you can simply run this code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;
$installer->removeAttribute('catalog_category', 'category_tagline_main');
$installer->endSetup();
```